# pandas data reader function for google finance can be really slow

Tags: python, pandas, google-finance

I am trying to get google finance data for stocks. However, sometimes it hangs and takes 30 seconds to a minute, and sometimes it runs in less than 5 seconds.

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime

stock = DataReader('TSLA', 'google', datetime(2010,1,1), datetime(2016,1,1))
```

What's the reason for this? Is there a queue for data? Do I have a limit to how many times I can call the API in a fixed time period?

Thanks!

Comment: If you more frequently than response time will increase. Usually, there are limits to how many calls you can make in minute to reduce load on server

Comment: How many time did you tried to run code ?

Comment: Maybe like 10-20 times.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to ask how frequently did you ran API call like 10 call per min

Comment: I think it's my router. I tethered my iphone's internet to my computer and it downloaded significantly faster. Do you know of anything in the router that would cause it download stock data so slowly?

Comment: And to answer your first question, maybe I called the API once or twice per minute for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the time of your request
Pause three minutes and it will recover